# Find $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{\sec^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can we find

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{\sec^2 x}dx$$

I tried $t=\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ but this seems not work. Any hints?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, though I may be wrong.  I used NIntegrate on Mathematica for an answer of 2.92475 if that helps.

Comment: @russCam : If you mean finding it in closed form is not possible, then maybe you should say so.  The question doesn't explicitly require closed form (although the proposed substitution does seem to be an attempt in that direction).

Comment: My apologies for the assumption.

Comment: Change variables to get $\int_1^2 \frac{e^y}{y\sqrt{y-1}}$.  Still not closed form, but it looks much better.

Answer (score 5):

Via [Owen T function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwenT.html) and

> [What is the antiderivative of $\displaystyle\int e^{c\sec^2(x)}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613212/what-is-antiderivative-of-f-theta-where-f-theta-cos-2-pi-sqrt-1/4746074#4746074):

$$\int_0^\frac\pi4e^{\sec^2(x)}dx=2\pi \operatorname T(i\sqrt2,1)$$

Now use this [special case formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=OwenT%28x%2C1%29) and apply the [imaginary error function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=erfi%28x%29):

$$\boxed{\int_0^\frac\pi4e^{\sec^2(x)}dx=\frac\pi4(\operatorname{erfi}^2(1)+1)=2.92474829320277\dots}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}e^{\sec^2 x}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sec^{2n}x}{n!}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}dx+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sec^{2n}x}{n!}~dx$

$=[x]_0^\frac{\pi}{4}+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sec^{2n-2}x}{n!}~d(\tan x)$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(1+\tan^2x)^{n-1}}{n!}~d(\tan x)$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{C_{k-1}^{n-1}\tan^{2k-2}x}{n!}~d(\tan x)$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(n-1)!\tan^{2k-1}x}{n!(n-k)!(k-1)!(2k-1)}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{4}$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{n(n-k)!(k-1)!(2k-1)}$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n(n-k)!(k-1)!(2k-1)}$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(n+k+1)n!k!(2k+1)}$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\int_0^1\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{t^{n+k}}{n!k!(2k+1)}~dt$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\int_0^1\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{t^ke^t}{k!(2k+1)}~dt$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^k\dfrac{(-1)^{k-n}t^ne^t}{n!(2k+1)}\right]_0^1$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Indefinite_integral)

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^k\dfrac{(-1)^{k-n}e}{n!(2k+1)}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$

$=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{k-n}e}{n!(2k+1)}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ke}{n!(2n+2k+1)}$

$=\dfrac{e}{2}\Phi_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2},1,\dfrac{3}{2};-1,1\right)$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series)