# What is antiderivative of $f(\theta)$, where $f(\theta) = \cos {( 2\pi \sqrt{ 1 + a^2 } \sec^2(\theta))}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

**CONTEXT**

[Note: this post has been altered from its original]

I am working on a problem relating to the Huygens–Fresnel principle [1]. Namely, I am attempting to superimpose the secondary wavelets formed at the wavefront and obtain the primary wave back. In order to normalize the amplitude of the secondary waves, I need to solve this integral.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain how to integrate the following, or just solve the following.

**QUESTIONS**

By $a$, I denote a real-valued constant.

Q.1:

What is 
$$\int  
  \cos {  \left( 2\pi   \sqrt{  1 +  a^2  }
   \sec^2(\theta)  \right)} 
     d\theta
?$$

Q.2:

How could one approach determining the antiderivative?

**BILBIOGRAPHY**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle#Mathematical_expression_of_the_principle

Comment: In case an elementary antiderivative does not exist, do you have specific bounds you wish to compute this integral with? Edit: Wolfram seems to state rather authoritatively that a closed form antiderivative with its standard library does not exist, so the bounds are critical.

Comment: Then the integral as written diverges since near zero it looks like $\theta^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\T{\operatorname T}$

Let $c=2\pi\sqrt{a^2+1}$ and $\sec(\theta)=t$:

$$\int\cos(c\sec^2(\theta))d\theta=\operatorname{Re}\int\frac{e^{ic(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$$

and use the [Owen T function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=OwenT):

> $$\T(x,a)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^a \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$$

to get

$$\boxed{\int\cos(c\sec^2(\theta))dx=2\pi\operatorname{Re}\T\left((i-1)\sqrt c,\tan(\theta)\right)}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5BRe%28D%5B2%CF%80+OwenT%28%281-i%29+%E2%88%9Ac%2Ctan%28x%29%29%5D%29%5D). Using the [unnormalized Fresnel sine and cosine integrals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral):

$$\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos(c\sec^2(\theta))d\theta=\frac\pi2-\sqrt\frac\pi2\int_0^{\sqrt c}\cos(x^2)+\sin(x^2)dx=\frac\pi2-\sqrt\frac\pi2(\operatorname C(\sqrt c)+\operatorname S(\sqrt c))$$